# What's the number associated to your account "with" T-Mobile or "at" T-Mobile?

Tags: prepositions

quick question.

Which phrase sounds better?

> Can you please provide me the pin code associated to your account
>   **at** T-Mobile?

or

> Can you please provide me the pin code associated to your account
>   **with** T-Mobile?

Answer (score 3):

> Can you please provide me the pin code associated to your account **with/at** T-Mobile?

An account may be *with Z* or *at Z*, but most people would simply say "your T-Mobile account".

However, your sentence is unidiomatic in other ways

1. We speak of X being *associated **with** Y*, not ***to***.
2. Moreover, *associated with your account* is clunky; you would do better to use *for your T-Mobile account*.
3. There's really no need to mention either the *account* or the *code*—in any but the most formal registers these will be implicit.
4. *Could* is a shade less demanding than *can* in these contexts, and therefore "politer".

A much shorter way of phrasing this request would be

> Could you please provide me your T-Mobile PIN?

Comment: I agree with this answer - the question is better if phrased in this concise way.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> Can you please provide me the pin code *linked to* your account *with* T-Mobile?

Or possibly:

> Can you please provide me the pin code associated *with* your account *at* T-Mobile?

Either *with* or *at* works, though I think *with* sounds better. One normally says they have an account *with* a provider. *associated to* sounds weird to me, though other people may disagree- I have heard this phrase used before, but I find it jarring. *associated with* is a more common phrase, so I think this sounds more natural. But using “with” twice in one sentence would probably not sound good. So I would prefer the phrase *linked to* when talking about the pin.